# HTML5 CSS3 content boredered with empty space, not same width of navigation bar items, impossible to center heading

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've got some weird problems.
Why is my content surrounded with empty space?

```
jsfiddle.net/qyqt24dw/
```

How to center heading?
How to make navigation bar buttons the same size and higher?
I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All web browsers had default styles that they add. These are there own idea of how certain things like headers and paragraphs should be styled.
A good starting point is to download a css file like normalize.css that tries to create consistency across all browser.
[download normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

web browsers also have developer tools that you can use to inspect what the box model is doing (how much padding and margin is being added, etc.) It also shows what css is being used, which you can disable using the tick boxes. It is an essential tool for trying to figure out what is going wrong.

**Rigth-click** object and select **Inspect Element**.